# What exactly does the selectnbrecv function from Go do?

Tags: go, reverse-engineering

I'm reverse engineering a Go binary and came across the function `selectnbrecv`. However, I don't understand the [documentation](https://golang.org/src/runtime/chan.go?s=20089:20153#L699). I'll appreciate it if someone can explain to me the context and operation of the function. Thanks!

Comment: Hint: the nb in selectnbrecv stands for non-blocking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the Go runtime internal implemetaion for non blocking receive from the channel:
When the channel has any events the `selectnbrecv` function returns `true` otherwise returns `false` (for `nil` channel returns `false`):
It receives on channel and writes the received data to `v` (if `&v` is not nil, in which case received data is ignored.) If  no data are available, returns `false`. Otherwise, if the channel is closed, zeros `v` and returns `true`. Otherwise, fills in `v` with a data and returns `true`.

```
// compiler implements
//
//  select {
//  case v = <-c:
//      ... foo
//  default:
//      ... bar
//  }
//
// as
//
//  if selectnbrecv(&v, c) {
//      ... foo
//  } else {
//      ... bar
//  }
//
func selectnbrecv(elem unsafe.Pointer, c *hchan) (selected bool) {
    selected, _ = chanrecv(c, elem, false) // false for non blocking
    return
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what the question links to.

Comment: @wasmup By element you mean bytes of data? Also, there is a typo in the word "receive" on the first line of your response in case you wanna fix it :)

Comment: Yes `data` (value of a specified element type), see new update. e.g. `int` type for `chan int`, ...

Comment: @wasmup Thank you for the answer. I don't have enough reputation to upvote it. Sorry!

Comment: @wasmup So I did some reading on the "select" part. Basically it's a `switch-case` thing as what to do in various cases, right?

Comment: @wasmup I'm really struggling with the concept of "select" here. Since the return value is called "selected" and the type of reading is non-blocking, I'm thinking whenever there is data available, the channel is gonna be selected, i.e., the return value selected is true. In other words, does the word "select" refer to the channel?

Comment: @Newbie Yes and yes. The compiler implements `select` using `if else` e.g. like `switch case`. When the channel has any events the `selectnbrecv` function returns `true` - `selected` is just a name to convey meaning, When the channel has any events: a  call to `close(channel)` without data is also an event so this function returns `true` too. see the  comments inside the code in my answer.

Comment: @wasmup I went through the comments. I think the description https://golang.org/src/runtime/chan.go?s=20089:20153#L699 is equivalent to what you said. I sort of started with `chanrecv` which returns `bool` for both `received` and `selected`. The "channel close" event you emphasized I think is categorized as `selected=true, received=false`, right? Other than that I think `selected=true, received=true` represents data being present in the channel so the channel gets selected, `selected=false, received=true` doesn't make sense in non-blocking mode, and `selected=false, received=false` is trivial.